# With[{a=1},{b=a},b] in 13.2 does evaluate to 1

Tags: core-language, scoping

This isn't documented, and the front end highlights the second comma and third argument in red, but it's used in DownValues[Once][[3]] and is very convenient. Anyone know more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid nested With\[\]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with) -- See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with/54874#54874) in particular.

Comment: Getting proper syntax coloring is apparently not a trivial undertaking. Until that happens I doubt it will be documented. But the change that allowed this syntax is intended to be permanent.

Comment: I think two comments, by [István Zachar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10432/106#comment156518_10432) and [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109298/106#296006_109298) are worth cross-referencing, as is [IterateWith](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/inactive-objects/transform-code.html). "Normally, later `With` variables are unaware of earlier variables’ values". Compare `With[{a = 3, b = a + 2, c = a + b}, {a, b, c}]` to `With[{a = 3}, {b = a + 2}, {c = a + b}, {a, b, c}]` ...

Comment: ....  But why is this not better documented?  A similar comment could be applied to obtaining a [stable sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192557/106)